# When does a kafka connect SourceTask fail?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am looking into emitting metrics when a SourceTask fails for specific reasons only, my current understanding is that whenever start or poll encounters an unhandled exception source task enters failed state.

This got me curious about the lifecycle of a SourceTask.

is my understanding correct? can it fail for reasons when poll doesn't throw any error?

also would every instance of "entering into failed state" trigger the stop method within the SourceTask or can it happen that stop isn't triggered?